# In OpenGL, with depth test enabled, still find some triangles overlaps wrongly

Tags: c, opengl, sfml

I rotate the box around X axis

those are images taken when running my code:

[example1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/btFQl.png)

[example2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/abgAY.png)

[example3 a plane has lost](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2nb5F.png)

I used `glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST)`, and `glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT)`before drawing.

why?

Comment: Does the default frame buffer have a depth buffer? This depends on the window framework and OS. It may be necessary to specify a depth buffer before creating the OpenGL context. See [Using OpenGL in a SFML window](https://www.sfml-dev.org/tutorials/2.5/window-opengl.php).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your window (default framebuffer) doesn't have a depth buffer at all. You have to setup a OpenGL window with a depth buffer by using the [`sf::ContextSettings`](https://www.sfml-dev.org/documentation/2.5.1/structsf_1_1ContextSettings.php) class.

See [Using OpenGL in a SFML window](https://www.sfml-dev.org/tutorials/2.5/window-opengl.php):

```cpp
ContextSettings settings;
settings.depthBits = 24;
```